# Why dependency injection is not working in post ASP.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am injecting two classes in my controller.

In the get request, when I put a break point, I can see there is an instance being retrieved in the constructor .

However in the post action, the instance is null ?

here is my controller class;

```
using BethanyPieShop.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BethanyPieShop.Controllers
{
    public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        public IOrderRepository _orderRepository { get; set; }
        public ShoppingCart _shoppingCart { get; set; }

        public OrderController(IOrderRepository _orderRepository, ShoppingCart _shoppingCart)
        {
            _orderRepository = _orderRepository;
            _shoppingCart = _shoppingCart;
        }
        public IActionResult Checkout()
        {

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Checkout(Order order)
        {
            // Null here _shoppingCart
            var items = _shoppingCart.GetShoppingCartItems();
            _shoppingCart.ShoppingCartItems = items;

            if (_shoppingCart.ShoppingCartItems.Count == 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your cart is empty, add some pies first");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _orderRepository.CreateOrder(order);
                _shoppingCart.ClearCart();
                return RedirectToAction("CheckoutComplete");
            }
            return View(order);
        }


        public IActionResult CheckoutComplete()
        {
            ViewBag.CheckoutCompleteMessage = ", thanks for your order. You'll soon enjoy our delicious pies!";
            return View();
        }


    }
}
```

I registered the services in the main class:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ShoppingCart>();
```

Comment: Your parameters have the same name as the fields so the hide them. I suspect you already get compiler warnings about this. Your code is assigning the parameter value to the parameter itself

Comment: Don't use leading underscores in parameter names. By convention a leading underscore is only used in private fields.

Answer (score 5):

You are setting a variable with the same name. Without using a 'this.' statement. Try changing the following from

```
public OrderController(IOrderRepository _orderRepository, ShoppingCart _shoppingCart)
{
    _orderRepository = _orderRepository;
    _shoppingCart = _shoppingCart;
}
```

to

```
public OrderController(IOrderRepository orderRepository, ShoppingCart shoppingCart)
    {
        _orderRepository = orderRepository;
        _shoppingCart = shoppingCart;
    }
```

Comment: It's worth explaining why the problem occurred in the first place - the parameters are defined in the constructor's scope so they hide the fields with the same name defined in an outer scope. I think the compiler already generates a warning for this. Resharper certainly does

Answer (score 1):

So I think you should use this. Like this:

```
public OrderController(IOrderRepository _orderRepository, ShoppingCart _shoppingCart)
    {
        this._orderRepository = _orderRepository;
        this._shoppingCart = _shoppingCart;
    }
```

Comment: The real solution would be to *not* use an underscore in a public member parameter

Comment: True, I personly would make those variables private readonly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks i wll change it

Comment: @JorneSchuurmans thanks I wll change it